# why does queryset values() in django do not access @property

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with `@property` methods in Django 2.0. When I use `Object.objects.all().values()` I expected to get also the getters of these property models returned, but unfortunately only the class constants (table fields) are returned. Is this a missing feature or is it intended by design?

Comment: The ORM only fetches the *fields* in the *database*, no properties, methods, or other attributes you assign to such model object.

Comment: You can make annotations to calculate certain objects at the database side, but the ORM is designed to only construct queries, not logic located in the model.

Comment: that means, methods of querysets do not have any knowledge of the model class?

Comment: they have, in the sense that if you write `.values('foo')` and `foo` is a `ForeignKey`, it will be translated to `foo_id`, but they do *not* convert it to a `Model` object, hence they do not do anything with the non-field attributes.